# Programmatically determine AWS account Id of a particular IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a web tool which allows IAM users to do magic with their AWS account. Considering I have a free plan, any AWS user could create new IAM users once the trial has ended, so they would eventually never pay for my service.
Is there any way to know the Aws Account Id of a particular IAM user? That way I can store that ID on db and block any other new IAM user coming from that particular AWS account.

Comment: Do you have credentials for these users? How are they identified to you at the moment?

Comment: Yes, I do have their Access Key ID and the Secret Access Key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the iam [GetUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html) then that call returns (among other things) the ARN for the user, which includes the account id. You don't need to know the user name to call it - if none is specified it uses the calling user.

A call like **aws iam get-user**

Would return:

```
{
  "User": {
    "UserName": "test",
    "PasswordLastUsed": "2015-01-18T11:08:07Z",
    "CreateDate": "2014-10-21T20:30:04Z",
    "UserId": "AIDAXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Path": "/",
    "Arn":  "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/test"
  }
}
```

The ARN (Amazon Resource Number (arn)) for iam entities is of the format `arn:aws:iam::account-number:resource`, so you just need to extract this portion ( **123456789012**) from it. You can't guarantee that latter portions won't also contain digits, so you should split on `:` and take the 5th component.

Answer (score 5):

From CLI

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

If you use IAM based calls (same as what other people suggested) your IAM user needs to have proper permissions for those calls but sts one should go through for any IAM user.

Answer (score 2):

> Ruby SDK

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'pp'
require 'colorize'

current_region='us-west-2'
current_profile='default'

Aws.config.update({
                      region: current_region,
                      credentials: Aws::SharedCredentials.new(profile_name: current_profile),
                  })

iam = Aws::IAM::Client.new
client = iam.get_account_authorization_details({
                                                   max_items: 1,
                                               })
resp=client.user_detail_list[0].arn
acc="#{resp}".split(":")[4]
puts acc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Get-IAMUser and get the information, including the ARN; parsing the ARN would have the Account ID as well. Screenshot below.

**PowerShell**

```
Import-Module AWSPowerShell.psd1
Get-IAMUser
```

[image]

**Boto**

```
import boto
iam = boto.connect_iam()
iam.get_user()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Python boto2 variant in case you don't have access/permissions for `iam.get_user()`

```
import boto.utils

print boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['iam']['info']['InstanceProfileArn'].split(':')[4]
```